Steamworks web API ConsumeItem returns empty Json
I want to make a system for exchanging items of one rarity for items of another rarity. To do this, I want to remove items of lower rarity in order to give the player an item of better rarity, respectively. I use Steamworks Web Api and the ConsumeItem method, the problem is that Steam returns me an empty Json and the items are not deleted, here is an example of server code with the structure:
    private async Task<bool> RemoveItemsFromInventory(string steamId, List<int> itemIds)
    {
        var content = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> 
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("key", ItemPurchase.steamWebApiKey),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("steamid", steamId),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("appid", "3081680"),
        };
 
        for (int i = 0; i < itemIds.Count; i++)
        {
            content.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>($"itemid[{i}]", itemIds[i].ToString()));
            content.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>($"quantity[{i}]", "1"));
        }
 
        foreach (var pair in content)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{pair.Key}: {pair.Value}");
        }
 
        var encoded = new FormUrlEncodedContent(content);
 
        var response = await client.PostAsync($"https://api.steampowered.com/IInventoryService/ConsumeItem/v1", encoded);
 
        string responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
 
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Request successful.");
            Console.WriteLine("Response: " + responseContent);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Request failed with status code: " + response.StatusCode);
            Console.WriteLine("Response: " + responseContent);
            return false;
        }
    }

